# Use Faker gem to generate correlated city, postal code, country code values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

Is there a way to get the [Faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker) to generate 'correlated' city and country code values?

For example,

- Vancouver, CA
- Minneapolis, MN

I'm doing this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :location do
    ...
    city {Faker::Address.city}
    country_code {['US', 'CA'].sample}
    ...
  end
end
```

But there is no guarantee that the `city` will actual reside in `country_code`.

I'd settle for something like:

```
postal_code {Faker::Address.postcode(['US', 'CA'].sample) }
```

Which I could then geocode to get the other values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize based on locales: https://github.com/stympy/faker#customization

So you can create or modify a locale file, see this example: https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/locales/en-NEP.yml

Then you can set what the default country should be and also what states do you want to use

Comment: on a side note, im wondering if the faker gem is reliable in terms of not breaking your tests (e.g: the generated code text duplicates and stuff like that)